# Define a rule for double-type in ANTLR v4

Tags: java, metaprogramming, antlr4

I *wrote* this grammar (*.g4):

```
ID  : [a-zA-Z]+;
INT : [0-9];
DBL : INT+ (PT INT+)?;    
PT  : '.';
...

prog: stat+;
stat: expr NEWLINE              # printExpr
    | ID EQL expr NEWLINE       # assign
    | 'clear'                   # clear
    | NEWLINE                   # blank
    ;

expr: expr op=(MUL|DIV) expr    # MulDiv
    | expr op=(ADD|SUB) expr    # AddSub
    | DBL                       # double
    | ID                        # id
    | LBR expr RBR              # parens
    ;
```

My ANTLR and Java files compile with no problems, but if I run this input:

```
193.2
a =5.2
b= 6
c= a+b*2.2
c
```

there is a problem with `b= 6` **line 3:3 no viable alternative at input '6'**
followed by a `nullPointerException` on the `visit()`.

I assume there might be some ambiguity within my `expr` rule.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hint: 6.1 is working. But isn't 6 also a double (6.0) ?

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem!
Defining my previous `DBL` as:

```
dbl : INT+ PT INT+
    | PT INT+
    | INT+
    ;
```

**It did the trick!!**

Comment: Still don't know why. What is the difference between lowecase and uppercase rules? I should ask this in a new question

Comment: uppercase rules are called Lexer rules. lowercase rules are called Parser rules. ANTLR works first by splitting the input into tokens using the Lexer rules. Then on a second pass, it uses the defintions of Parser rules (made of parser rules and lexer tokens) to parse the file. -- See these links for more info: https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Lexer+Rules   https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Parser+Rules